# Ставятся ли кавычки? Почему?

Tags: пунктуация

У того спортсмена был номер "4".
Спортсмен под номером "4" первым достиг цели.
Номер "4", подойдите, пожалуйста, к стойке регистрации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каких случаях нужны кавычки?
В современном русском языке кавычки выполняют следующие функции:

1. Выделение безабзацной прямой речи и цитат.
2. Выделение условных (собственных) наименований.
3. Выделение слов, которые употребляются в необычном, ироническом, особом значении.

([Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1)).

**Номер 4** из Вашего вопроса не относится ни к одному из перечисленных пунктов, поэтому кавычки не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не нужны. Иначе все номера писались бы в кавычках. Чем отличается номер спортсмена от номера дома или квартиры?

Comment: Не очень научный ответ на вопрос "почему?"

Comment: "Наука" на пустом месте выглядит смешно. Она не для того, наука-то.